# How can I make the "Show desktop" function only hide the windows on a specific monitor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I have three monitors and have a problem with the "Show desktop" function in Windows.

Whenever I hit the icon, all windows will be hidden but I only want to hide all the windows on monitor X.

Is this possible?

Comment: Here's a free solution <https://superuser.com/a/1819069/1866885>, Works fine on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/).  It costs $39.99, but it has a few other really useful features, like Taskbars on the non-primary monitors.

Right-click System Tray icon > Window Management > This Monitor > Show the Desktop

Or, you can make a keyboard hotkey to Show Desktop on only the monitor where the mouse is.

[image: UltraMon]

Answer (score 4):

**It is possible for free.** [Swap Screen](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/swapscreen.html) is very simple program to do that. You have to define other shortcut than <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, but I still find it convinient enough. For example I bound <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to show desktop 1, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to show desktop 2.

Additionally, this program have some other neat features. One that I find myself using daily is function to **move windows to another monitor** with a shortcut, then there are sticky cursor and plenty other features. Swap Screen is a part of DualMonitorTools, free set of tools for multiple monitors that can provide even more functionality.

Here is the screen:

[image: swap screen]