# Can you use the Windows + D shortcut for one monitor only?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a dual monitor setup, I also like to use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut to bring the desktop into view. When I use this shortcut the windows open in both monitors minimize and the desktop is shown.

Is there any way to have only the active monitor show the desktop and have the other window keep all its windows as they were?

Comment: Try right clicking on the start bar at the bottom and clicking show the desktop. Not sure if that is the same as win+D

Comment: @soandos - It is.

Comment: I have wrote my solution [here](http://superuser.com/a/1144293/662284). hope can help you.

Comment: Are you trying to keep a specific window open on your other display?  If so, another option you might want to consider would be to potentially keep the window on Always-On-Top mode?  This can be done through, e.g., AHK.

Answer (score 11):

**It is possible for free.** [Swap Screen](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/swapscreen.html) is very simple program to do that. You have to define other shortcut than <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, but I still find it convinient enough. For example I bound <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to show desktop 1, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to show desktop 2.

Additionally, this program have some other neat features. One that I find myself using daily is function to **move windows to another monitor** with a shortcut, then there are sticky cursor and plenty other features. Swap Screen is a part of DualMonitorTools, free set of tools for multiple monitors that can provide even more functionality.

Here is the screen:

[image: swap screen]

Comment: Not working on windows 8

Comment: @Userpassword strange, it is working for me on **Windows 8** and **Windows 10**. May I help you with that somehow?

Comment: So its no possible to bind WIN + D :: and when you try other key like ALT + D will be minimize but not toggle

Comment: Not really the same, as pressing the hotkey again does nothing, while the original `win`+`d` maximises back the previously minimised windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) you can easily do this with a Hotkey.  In the Options menu simply go to the Hotkey tab and scroll down to the option *Show the desktop on monitor with mouse* and assign any key combo that you'd like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to do what you ask.  The best tools for managing multiple monitors appears to be [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/overview/) and [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Taskbar/).  They are not free, but a quick look through the features and it appears DisplayFusion may do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This project can help you very well: https://github.com/ruzrobert/ShowDesktopOneMonitor

He uses <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> by default to return to the desktop

Can be used with [Keyboard Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) of [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/), he can map <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, This can perfectly solve the problem you raised

add keymap tutorial
[image]