# Windows 8: Win+d only for first display

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you use the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut for one monitor only?](https://superuser.com/questions/334720/can-you-use-the-windows-d-shortcut-for-one-monitor-only)

Is it possible to implement? It's very annoying when working on multiple displays and need to see desktop only of first monitor. Pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> minimizes all windows on all monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible to implement :)

This solution might be considered an advanced one since it requires programming, for example in C++ or C# ([here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) a good article how to do it in C#).

I cannot post more than 2 hyperlinks so you'll have to get documentation for each function on your own (just search for it on MSDN).

For your issue you'd have to use WinAPI to:

- enumerate monitors using [EnumDisplayMonitors function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- enumerate all top-level windows using EnumWindows function
- match monitors with windows using MonitorFromWindow function
- determine which windows to minimize
- send WM_SYSCOMMAND message with value SC_MINIMIZE to appropriate windows using SendMessage function

Comment: I will take hours to code something that would do this reliably :)